# Spring Data JPA: Saving nested OneToMany children (with cascading) returns NULL parent foreign object

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, jackson

I have two Model Objects: Parent and Child. The model classes are as follows:

```
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
class Parent(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Int? = 0,
        val name: String? = "",
        val age: Int? = null,

        @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.MERGE])
        @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
        val children: List<Child>?= mutableListOf()
)


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "children")
class Child(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Int? = 0,
        val name: String? = "",
        val age: Int? = null,

        @ManyToOne
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = ["name", "age", "children"], allowSetters = true)
        val parent: Parent?
)
```

In the parent object there is a property called "Children" that takes an array of Child Objects. This children property has @OneToMany annotation with cascading set to CascadeType.MERGE. Also it has @JoinColumn annotation with name argument set to "parent_id"

In the Child object the "parent" property has @ManyToOne annotation along with @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation where its value is set to "children". This is used to prohibit infinite recursive loop from taking place while serialized by Jackson.

The problem I'm facing is while saving Parent object (with nested children objects in array) by a Route. So when I'm saving a parent object such as this one:

```
{
    "name": "Tom's Dad",
    "age": 55,
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Tom",
            "age": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "Jerry",
            "age": 22
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting the following JSON saved result:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Tom's Dad",
    "age": 55,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "Tom",
            "age": 20,
            "parent": null
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "Jerry",
            "age": 22,
            "parent": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that in the nested children list the foreign parent object is NULL.  The Problem with this result arises in the frontend Angular app that I am using. The Angular app saves the returned Parent object along with nested children objects where parent foreign property is set to null. So if I Re-Save or update the Parent object, the foreign_key in the database is set to NULL and the relationship between these parents and children objects are terminated.

I want to know is there a way where upon saving the parent object, the returned children objects will have parent object with them such as the following:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Tom's Dad",
    "age": 55,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "Tom",
            "age": 20,
            "parent": {
                "id": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "Jerry",
            "age": 22,
            "parent": {
                "id": 10
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the controller class. This entire example is recreated for simplification purpose. So no service class is used.

```
package com.example.parentchild

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*


@RestController
@CrossOrigin
class Route(val parentRepo: ParentRepo){


    @PostMapping("/parent/save")
    fun saveParent(@RequestBody parent: Parent) = this.parentRepo.save(parent)

    @GetMapping("/parent/all")
    fun getAllParents() = this.parentRepo.findAll()


    @GetMapping("/parent/{id}")
    fun getAllParents(@PathVariable id: Int) = this.parentRepo.findById(id).get()
}
```

Comment: Do you necessarily need the parent object in the list of children?

Comment: I know what you mean. But I need it for convenient's sake. I don't need the entire parent object though, all I need is each parent object with just the id. Hence you can see I have added an annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties where I have added all properties of parent class except the id.

Comment: Of course in time of resaving the parent object I can manually put the id in the child object's parent property manually from front end application, but that's what I have been trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy paste here the controller and service code, please?